# Using JQuery on SharePoint. Scripts work in a Fiddle on both browsers, but doesn't work on page in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Using SharePoint 2010 on-prem. Loading up some JS in a content editor webpart to show some data when a button is clicked. After my first attempt I had it working in Chrome but nothing would happen in IE. It's a simple removeClass function and it is working on my fiddle in both browsers: https://jsfiddle.net/1kqhmL2j/1/
I have had issues using show/hide in the past which is why I'm using a Display: none class. Everything is !important because SharePoint.

Not really sure where to start on the trouble shoot, as most searches of these terms don't seem to get me anything SharePoint specific. Have tried using the JQuery library directly on page as opposed to linked from Google's CDN, played with where it loads on the page, etc. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

The scripts:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".but1").click(function(){ 

                    $(".blurb1").removeClass("hidden");


                });
         }); 

$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".but2").click(function(){ 

                    $(".blurb2").removeClass("hidden");


                });
         }); 

$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".but3").click(function(){ 

                    $(".blurb3").removeClass("hidden");


                });
         }); 

$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".but4").click(function(){ 

                    $(".blurb4").removeClass("hidden");


                });
         }); 

$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".but5").click(function(){ 

                    $(".blurb5").removeClass("hidden");


                });
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an earlier version of JQuery solved it - sorry folks

Comment: To elaborate on why that works, SharePoint 2010 generally needs Internet Explorer to run in compatibility mode. Compatibility mode emulates IE8, which is not compatible with the latest versions of jQuery.

Comment: That clarifies it 100% - thank you so much Thriggle, it is indeed in compatibility mode to use infopath. Is there a way I can give you votes or points etc for your comment?

Comment: Nope, but that's okay--I have plenty of points! I suggest accepting your own answer, since it'll be useful for other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your environment, is basic JavaScript working?  i.e. is it a problem that JavaScript itself is not working, as opposed to just an issue with your script syntax?

Comment: I just tested with an alert box and it came up fine.